# restricting facebook login permissions

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, authentication, facebook-login

I am wondering if there is a way in which I can only allow users to login to a website with the facebook login only if they are connected to certain networks, like universities for instance. Is there a way to make these restrictions?

Comment: No, because to get this information you must login the user first. Unless you make the user grant his information and after checking his data e you say "Hey sorry for asking all your personal data, but it seems you can't use my app. But hey, thanks anyway, your personal data is safe and I won't do anything with it"

Comment: What if the user logs in, then the system checks the network theyre connected to on facebook with the granted permissions, then logs them in completelty, or tells them they cannot login?

Comment: that's up to you, you can create a session and keep them logged, you can ask them to join the network you want or you can simply destroy the session and force fb.logout();